# Is there an "Idiot proof" way to re-enable all fields (regardless of there state) on a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, field

My problem is that I have javascript that enables/disables some form fields that I have disabled by default that the user doesn't need to send to my business, but can enable them if they need to with a checkbox. However, I obviously have a form provider that is quite finnicky about disabled fields. Basically, the visitor will select checkboxes that will enable certain fields that they need to enter, or choose to.

What I'm curious about, can I create a checkbox that will undo all the fields enabled or disabled state to just enabled, regardless of it's current state, so that all fields get submitted?

Another reason I need this kind of function is because the client receives an autoresponce e-mail, and when the fields are disabled they see %FeildName% if the field was disabled before submitting the form. simply because the field never existed when the data was submitted on the form, obviously because of it's disabled state.

If something can be done, can it be entered in my existing javascript code? I already have a Form Validation script, that I used with javascript.

I'm not exactly great at javascript, and never really even played with jQuery before, nor do I have the intellect to follow jQuery, so any help would be appreciated.

My code can be seen on this page, just view the source.
http://www.gbjimaging.net/order/form/complete/audio.htm

The checkbox at the very bottom of the form, before the submit and reset buttons I'd like to perform this function, so that all information is garenteed to be submitted. Again, thanks for your anticipated help, and it really will be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't have the intellect to follow jQuery, you're in the wrong line of work. Are you planning to come running to SO for every script you need to write?

Comment: @Geno J, Try reading my answer! It has an example you need and basic info for newbies in order to start using jQuery!

Comment: @Barmar, "the intellect to follow jQuery", seriously? the fact that you think that there's only one way to do anything saddens me deeply...

Comment: @OneOfOne Those are his words, not mine.

Comment: Hey, I also did say that I am open minded. If there's a Dummies book on it, it's a best seller to me. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example is the way to make sure that all fields of your current form were re-enabled. All of the elements with `input, select, textarea` and `checkbox` tags will become enabled as you click a button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#switcher').click(function() {
    $('input, select').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('disabled')) {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
  });
});
```

#### [Online example](http://jsfiddle.net/XVq6a/2/)

You need to use jQuery and add it to your page by pasting the following to your page's head:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In this example Google CDN is being used.

Please read more about [jQuery Install](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp) and [jQuery Usage](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/).

Comment: Where does both of the above codes you provided go? I mean, I'm familiar with Javascript, and I know that the Form Validation that I use went in the head. I mean I don't want to sound like I'm completely clueless, but I did a lot of my form generating using form providers that did it all for me. To me, I've been always interested in web design, and have learned a lot on my own. I just know there's a lot more to learn. So, I'm sorry if I sound like I have no idea what I'm doing, but at least I'm willing to learn.

Comment: After going to that online example, I found that there would be a huge problem there. If I entered that using a checkbox, the checkbox would become disabled. On top of that, all existing fields that were disabled, would become enabled, and the enabled fields would become disabled. So, that code is a bit counterproductive, because it still presents the same problem, but now all the disabled fields are enabled, and enabled fields before are disabled.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is enable ONLY the current fields that were disabled should be re-enabled. For example, the extra phone number fields should be re-enabled, or the extra Item numbers. When I played with that code it disabled all enabled fields like FirstName, LastName and so on, and re-enabled all the disabled fields like the spair phone numbers, and the checkboxes, and item number details. ~ http://www.gbjimaging.net/order/form/complete/audio.htm

Comment: I made an example based on your form that after you click enable button, it will enable all `input, select, textarea` and `checkbox` fields, take a look at the updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/XVq6a/2/

Comment: In that case, where does the two examples of this code go? Judging by the first code, it looks like it may go in the head, but I'm not 100% sure. I'm not even sure if it can be added to an existing code. Because from the looks of it, it is what most people do on here, and specifically look at the function of javascript, and start there, when they don't add <script langruage="javascript"><!-- (then provide the code) --!> </script>.

Comment: Secondly, does the other code for jQuery looks like it can be added anywhere. So, any help is appreciated. I don't mean to be blunt, nor sound rude. I just am trying to get a grasp of this stuff. I'm willing to try anything, and I'm trying not to be judgemental in regards to any of the answers I've received. I'm just kinda over my head is all. ;)

Comment: Do you want to add it to your page?

Comment: Well... looking at the demonstration, and seeing it in action, yes. The only thing I'd do, is change the switcher to a checkbox.

Comment: The code works great. Curious though... instead of an Enable link, can it be a checkbox? I'd like the client to be able to check that box at the end of the form to enable all fields, and then hit Submit. The checkbox will mainly work for that purpose, but it will confirm the client has entered all information, to the best of their ability. My last comment... I promise. If you've got a responce, could you send it via comment or chat? Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, just found the id tag! thanks! Very much appreciated. Thanks everyone for your help and insight!

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy way to do this.  All you have to do is put all the field items in an Array, then when the user checks the checkbox, you can make an Array loop and for every item in the Array (`for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) if(checkBox.checked == true) {array[i].disabled = false;} else {array[i].disabled = true;}`).  This will disable all items if checkbox on uncheck, and enable on check.

Here is a small diagram:

[image: Diagram of code]

Comment: There is no `enabled` property, it should be `.disabled = false`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, I was using my knowledge of actionscript, I should've checked.  Anyways, it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery:

```
$(":input").prop('disabled', false);
```

`:input` is a jQuery pseudo-selector that matches all types of form input fields. The `.prop` method gets or sets properties, so this sets all the `disabled` properties to `false.`

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of :

```
function validate(OrderAudio) {
    if(valid) {
        var e = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), i;
        for(i = 0; i < e.length; ++i) {
            e[i].disabled = false;
        }
        e = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
        for(i = 0; i < e.length; ++i) {
            e[i].disabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this out. This looks the easiest route, without having to seriously remodify my whole form. Although, I may look into jQuery anyway, as it is becoming more and more evident that it's going to be unavoidable at some point.